# How to display first post in different format on wordpress page?

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I would like my first post to be differently styled and positioned above the current posts. I only like to get first post on the top in custom styled design, and the rest post below just as they already are. Top post width will be 1188px. I would be really glad if anybody knows how to do that. thank you.

Here is the picture what I want, first picture shows the current situation and the next picture shows what I want to achieve.

[image: picture one]
[image: picture two]

My current php entries are here:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<!-- Begin Content -->
<div id="content-a">

<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<div class="post">
<div class="imgdiv"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img src="<?php echo catch_that_image() ?>" width="250"></a></div>
<div class="p-heading"><h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1></div>
<div class="p-content">
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div>
<div class="p-info"><?php the_time('j.m.Y') ?> | <?php the_category(', '); ?> | <img src="http://www.virmodrosti.com/wp-content/uploads/comments.png" alt="Komentarji" width="26" height="12"><?php $totalcomments = get_comments_number(); echo $totalcomments; ?></div>

</div>

<?php endwhile; ?>

<div class="navigation">
<div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('Naslednja stran') ?></div>
<div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Prejšnja stran') ?></div>
<div class="clear"></div>
</div>

    <?php else : ?>

</div>
<div id="content">

<div class="post">
<div class="p-heading"><h1 class="center">Ni najdeno</h1></div>
<div class="p-content"><p class="center">Oprostite, ampak iščete nekaj kar ni tukaj.</p>
</div>
</div>
    <?php endif; ?>

         </div>

<!-- End Content -->
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Why not just use specific CSS styles that only target the first child in the post list? You should not have to worry about what is going on in the loop at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php $i=1; ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php if ($i == 1){

// here do the custom look you want to give to 1st post, i am sorry i dont know html
<div class="post">
<div class="imgdiv"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img src="<?php echo catch_that_image() ?>" width="250"></a></div>
<div class="p-heading"><h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1></div>
<div class="p-content">
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div>
<div class="p-info"><?php the_time('j.m.Y') ?> | <?php the_category(', '); ?> | <img src="http://www.virmodrosti.com/wp-content/uploads/comments.png" alt="Komentarji" width="26" height="12"><?php $totalcomments = get_comments_number(); echo $totalcomments; ?></div>

</div>
<?php } else { ?>

<div class="post">
<div class="imgdiv"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><img src="<?php echo catch_that_image() ?>" width="250"></a></div>
<div class="p-heading"><h1><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1></div>
<div class="p-content">
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>
</div>
<div class="p-info"><?php the_time('j.m.Y') ?> | <?php the_category(', '); ?> | <img src="http://www.virmodrosti.com/wp-content/uploads/comments.png" alt="Komentarji" width="26" height="12"><?php $totalcomments = get_comments_number(); echo $totalcomments; ?></div>

</div>
<?php } $i++; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: That is so great! Without all complication and unnecessary stuff! Thank you! You're a genius!

Comment: haha no bro nothin to be genius about, glad could help you :) @Techuser

Comment: I have a problem, maybe you should help me with that first post. That post needs his own div id="content-big" wrapper for example and not id="content-a" like the rest of the posts. Otherwise it cant be moved to the top because of the right sidebar, I want to remove div id="content-a" and replace with other id just for that post but it doesnt work that easily

Comment: I need that php code `<?php $i=1; ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<?php if ($i == 1){` to be between new div id for example`<div id="content-big"></div>` and the rest posts in `<div id="content-a"></div>` just as they already are.